# Chinese literature vocabulary

Tags: literary-chinese, literature

I'm looking for synonyms of everyday words, and I realized many of these "complicated words" are used in Chinese literature. Is there a name for this group of words? For example, we sometimes read 蓦然 in books which is actually just 猛然

Comment: Do 蓦然 and 猛然 really mean exactly the same thing?  The character 猛 by itself seems more ferocious that 蓦.

Comment: If  you like elegant or interesting words，why not read classic novels。 hard to read,but really plentiful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is: 书面语 . See http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%A6%E9%9D%A2%E8%AF%AD for more information